# Extending an existing Generic.xaml style from another WPF library

Tags: wpf, wpf-style, generic.xaml

I am working with the HandyControls WPF library, but I want to adjust one of its default styles. I want to add an 'OnClick' event to all NumericUpDown controls, using a Style which applies an EventSetter. I want this style to apply to all NumericUpDowns in my application, just as HandyControls' own **NumericUpDownBaseStyle** does.

I have a **Generic.xaml** file. I know it works, because I already have a style in here for one of our custom UserControls (one that the HandyControls library does not have its own style for), and that style gets applied *by default* to all instances of that custom control.

But when I add the following to *Generic.xaml*:

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:hc="https://handyorg.github.io/handycontrol"
x:Class="Generic">

<Style BasedOn="{hc:StaticResource NumericUpDownBaseStyle}" TargetType="hc:NumericUpDown">
    <EventSetter Event="MouseDown" Handler="OnClick"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>
```

the style is not applied to instances of **NumericUpDown**. Instead, **NumericUpDown** controls still use the default style from HandyControls.

If I place this style into a global resource dictionary (a dictionary which, since discovering Generic.xaml, I am trying to phase out), the style *is* applied, and I can see my **NumericUpDowns** turn red.

Why is my Generic.xaml file unable to take precedence over the styles defined in HandyControls? How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I posted my own answer to this a few days ago but that answer has been deleted? Great.

In the end I solved this by merging the external library into the dictionary at the top of Generic.xaml. I still have no idea why I had to do this.

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns:hc="https://handyorg.github.io/handycontrol">

    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- External Libraries -->
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/HandyControl;component/Themes/Theme.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Generic.xaml` is used to define the default style for a control. It's not used to extend or override a default style for a control that is defined in another assembly.

You should use a "global" style to do this, i.e. put your custom style that is based on the `NumericUpDownBaseStyle` directly in `App.xaml` or in a resource dictionary that is merged from `App.xaml`. Do not put it in `Generic.xaml`.

Comment: I don't have an App.xaml because this code is, itself, within a user controls library and not a WPF application. That's the entire reason I'm using a Generic.xaml file.